# Gradle does not recognize changes in jar manifest

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am new to gradle and try out some basic examples from the command line.

The example tells me to put this into my build.gradle file to make the class my main jar class.

```
jar.manifest.attributes 'Main-Class': 'de.gradlebuch.HelloWorld'
```

After that, the build output should look like this:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\gradle test\HelloWorld> gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE
```

Unfortunately, it isn't. I get:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\gradle test\HelloWorld> gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE
```

The jar and assembler task are UP_TO_DATE and the attribute is not in the Manifest.MF file.

When I do

```
gradle clean
gradle build
```

everything is fine. But I tought Gradle would be capable of detecting these kind of changes without rebuilding everyting.

What can I do to get Gradle detect changes in my build.gradle file?

Comment: What kind of changes are you talking about? Do you need to change your Main-Class propery often? Because if not, then you still have a jar with MANIFEST in it, because it was not repackaged. This task will execute each time, if you'll add some variable to the manifest, not the constant.

Comment: It is not about productive code yet. I am trying out some examples from a book i bought to learn gradle. And i am highly confused because one of the early examples is not working.

Comment: Seems to be strange, because if you have already a jar with the manifest inside and don't chande the mf content, then those manifest should be inside of jar. It can't disapear, because you don't pack a new jar.

Comment: Ok, it's a bug in gradle 2.5 - 2.7
https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3340

Comment: Oh, we have some projects, where we rely on gradle manifest task and just updated gradle version from 2.1 to 2.6. Thanks for reply, have to check, whether our build works still right

Comment: Same issue here. We're building a tar.gz providing an executable jar with its 3rd party dependencies in a subfolder. The MANIFEST.MF inside the JAR contains the classpath with all these libraries from runtime dependency. Changing only a 3rd dependency, i.e. by upgrading its version results in a UP-TO-DATE JAR-Task.